# Laravel new user sign up email dynamic error

Tags: php, laravel, email

I have a function of new user sign up that sends and email on registration.
When i go via the registration process it should store a record and then fire the email.

So i have used the `'Registered'` trait which is firing fine but I cant get the email address to pull from the data i have sent in

```
protected function registered(Request $request, $user)
{
        Mail::send('email.send', $user = ['name'=>$user['name'], 'surname'=>$user['surname'], 'email'=>$user['email']], function ($message) {
            $message->from('noreply@geniusmoney.co.uk');
            $message->sender('noreply@geniusmoney.co.uk');
            $message->to($user->email);
            $message->bcc('geniusteam@geniusmoney.co.uk');
            $message->subject('Welcome to Genius Money');
            $message->attach('attachments/contract10.pdf');
            $message->attach('attachments/entitychecklist.pdf');
            $message->from('noreply@geniusmoney.co.uk', 'Welcome to Genius Money');
        });
}
```

My error is:

> Undefined variable: user and that points to my $message->to

Comment: how are u calling the registered function please add that code

Comment: And which version of Laravel do you use?

Comment: You need to use `use($user)` in `Mail::send` after `function($message)` You can see my answer posted below!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are forgot to use `use($user)`. Add it in `Mail::send` after `function($message)`

Try below code:

```
protected function registered(Request $request, $user)
{
    Mail::send('email.send', $user = ['name'=>$user['name'], 'surname'=>$user['surname'], 'email'=>$user['email']], function ($message) use($user) {
        $message->from('noreply@geniusmoney.co.uk');
        $message->sender('noreply@geniusmoney.co.uk');
        $message->to($user->email);
        $message->bcc('geniusteam@geniusmoney.co.uk');
        $message->subject('Welcome to Genius Money');
        $message->attach('attachments/contract10.pdf');
        $message->attach('attachments/entitychecklist.pdf');
        $message->from('noreply@geniusmoney.co.uk', 'Welcome to Genius Money');
    });
}
```

Hope this will fixed it!

Comment: Glad, i could help you! :)

Answer (score 0):

Variables used in a closure need to be either declared as arguments or declared using the use keyword.

Using the use keyword gives the closure access to variables declared in an outer scope. e.g.

```
Mail::send(
    'email.send', 
    $user = array_only($user, ['name', 'surname', 'email']),
    function ($message) use (&$user) {
      ...
    }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to use $user inside the mail function callback,
replace

```
function ($message) {
```

with

```
function ($message) use ($user) {
```